# The program crashes on the phone (android)

Tags: python, android, mongodb, kivy, buildozer

I use Kivy and Python.
I made an application for Android, but after connecting the library for applications on the phone, I created a problem.
I am using MongoDB. After compiling the application to .apk on the phone, the program crashes.
I tried to remove everything related to this library and everything worked, but if I just import it, the program crashes on the phone.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Debug by reading the specific error as described in [these instructions](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/guide/android.html#debugging-your-application-on-the-android-platform).

You're probably using a library that is not supported on Android, or which you have not included in the android build.